# Custom content assist for default java editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, content-assist

I'm currently trying to develop an Eclipse Plugin to support code replacement, like what the default content assist in Eclipse do. What I want to implement is something like "insert argument names automatically on method completion with visualized box around the argument" and I can "use the Tab key to navigate between the inserted names" and "while navigating, list of optional variables for current argument can be displayed and be chosen".

In short, it comes to two questions:

1. How to add the visualized box around the already existed variable or even Java keywords that need replacement? And at the meanwhile I can use Tab key to switch between these boxes.
2. How to display a list of candidates to select from when I trigger on the box?

By now I only figure out the extension point : org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer may be useful, but I have no idea where to start at? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, finally I've solved it myself...

For the 'box', it should be the LinkedModeModel, this class should work with LinkedPositionGroup and LinkedPosition to add mutiple boxes. And we should use LinkedModeUI to set it up.

For the content assistant, there's no need to use the extension point. There is a ProposalPosition class which extends LinkedPosition for you to add your proposals for the 'box' in its constructor. And we can simply use the CompletionProposal to construct a ICompletionProposal array as the argument of ProposalPosition's constructor.